# Issue using Azure-iothub-device-client on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, azure, raspberry-pi, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to use the Python SDK for the IoT Hub by running the example code: "SimulatedDevice.py" but the code breaks on the same exception on 3 different raspbian devices as well as my PyCharm environment.
In trying to run the SimulatedDevice.py example on my Raspberry Pi, the code always breaks with an:

"ImportError: libboost_python-py27.so.1.62.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

initial error: "import iothub_client"

I have pip installed the azure-iothub-device-client as well as confirmed the version is python2.7 even trying to reinstall python. This is curious as when I run the exact same file on my Windows CMD the SimulatedDevice.py example code functions fine, it's only in the Python terminal and on the Raspberry Pi do I get this error.

Comment: You may refer suggestions outlined here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/126.

Answer (score 0):

As said in [this great post](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/126)

**1st solution**

- are you running raspbian stretch or jessie? You probably want stretch now. it's the latest stable and that's the one we're testing against
- is the `libboost-python1.62.0` package installed? if not you can install it with: 
    `apt-get install libboost-python1.62.0`

**2nd solution**

A user [ko5win] in that link with your same problem confirmed that a fresh raspberry pi with stretch and the proper version of libboost solved the pip version issue

Another user [sergiomfsilva] gives an alternative procedure:

**Environment** 
OS and version used

- Linux raspberrypi 4.14.30-v7+ #1102 SMP Mon Mar 26 16:45:49 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
- Python runtime used: Python 3.5.3
- SDK version used: 1.3.1

**Workaround steps used**

Get images and prepare to do the work:

- get last Raspbian Lite Image
- flash microSD card for Raspberry Pi3
- boot with raspberry pi
- login with pi user
- make the command 
  `sudo su`
- go to root folder 
  `cd /root`

**Update the system and make some time checks**

- Do the next commands: 
  `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` 
  `apt-get install ntp`
- Check the RPI date with the command 
  `date`

After date ok all its ready

Note: Configure ntp.conf file if date issues found

**Install required packages and review the error reported**

Install required packages

```
apt-get install -y git cmake build-essential curl libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev uuid-dev python3-pip
```

SDK cloning

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python.git
```

Install device client package using pip3

```
pip3 install azure-iothub-device-client
```

Go to samples folder

```
cd azure-iot-sdk-python/device/samples/
```

Run the sample code

```
python3 iothub_client_sample.py
```

The error must be the same:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  
>   File
> "iothub_client_sample.py", line 10, in  
>  import
> iothub_client File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/iothub_client/**init**.py",
> line 1, in  
>  from .iothub_client import * 
> ImportError: libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object
> file: No such file or directory

**Build new libraries and apply it**

- Go to building folder for linux 
  `cd /root/azure-iot-sdk-python/build_all/linux`
- Run Setup 
  `./setup.sh --python-version 3.5`
- Replace openssl dev with gnutls dev already reported like solution for a curl out of memory issue 
  `apt remove libcurl4-openssl-dev` 
  `apt install libcurl4-gnutls-dev`
- build libraries 
  `./build.sh --build-python 3.5`
- Go to root folder
  `cd /root`
- Move created library to python iothub_client path 
  `mv azure-iot-sdk-python/device/samples/iothub_client.so /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/iothub_client/iothub_client.so`
- Go to samples folder 
  `cd azure-iot-sdk-python/device/samples/`
- Run the sample code 
  `python3 iothub_client_sample.py`

This solves the issue found and works in the raspberry. This did not solve this issue because it is related with the pip package. To solve a new pip package with library and python version updated